# ¿ Cómo puedo, en JS, hacer sonar audio dentro de un bucle esperando a que en cada vuelta del bucle espere a que el sonido termine de reproducirse?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, sonido

Supongamos que tengo un string compuesto por puntos y rayas (código morse) y tengo un sonido para el punto y otro sonido para la raya. Recorro el string con un bucle y si encuentra un punto reproduce el sonido del punto, si encuentra una raya reproduce el sonido de la raya, pero en cada vuelta tiene que esperar a que termine el sonido
El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
let snPunto = new Audio("assets/sound/punto.wav");
let snRaya  = new Audio("assets/sound/raya.wav");

function playMorse(text) {
    for(let i = 0; i <= text.length-1; i++){
        if(text[i] == '.') snPunto.play();
        if(text[i] == '-') snRaya.play();
    }
}

let codigo = '...---...';
playMorse(codigo);
```

Pero ésto me devuelve un pitido largo. **¿ Cómo puedo hacer ésto ?** . Muchas gracias.

Comment: Intenta con la documentación: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp Me late que tendrías todos los elementos para hacerlo funcionar. Saludos :D

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas reproducir cada sonido y esperar a que termine para pasar al siguiente. Lo más recomendable es usar el evento [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) para saber en qué momento avanzar.

Revisa los comentarios en el código para saber lo que hace cada cosa.

```
// Definir origen de los sonidos
let punto = 'assets/sound/punto.wav';
let raya = 'assets/sound/raya.wav';
// Crear un solo elemento de audio
let audio = new Audio();

// Crear función para reproducir
function playMorse(text) {
    // Iniciar en -1, porque se hará un incremento al ingresar a la función
    let position = -1;
    // Aquí es donde se va a controlar la reproducción
    function audioPlay() {
        // Avanzar
        position ++;
        // Si ya se terminó de reproducir todo el código
        if(position >= text.length) {
            // Cancelar evento y salir de la función
            audio.removeEventListener('ended', audioPlay);
            return;
        }
        // Seleccionar sonido a reproducir de acuerdo a caracter actual
        audio.src = (text[position] == '.') ? punto : raya;
        // Reproducir
        audio.play();
    }
    // Asegurar avance cuando termine el sonido actual
    audio.addEventListener('ended', audioPlay);
    // Aquí es donde realmente inicia la reproducción
    audioPlay();
}

let codigo = '...---...';
playMorse(codigo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Crea una función que espere cierto determinado tiempo  para ejecutar el audio

```
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,ms))
}

async function playMorse(str){
    const letters = str.split('')
    for (let name of letters) {        
            if(name === '.'){console.log('bit')}
            if(name === '_'){console.log('raya')}
            await timeout(1000)
    }
}


playMorse('..._')
```